# How do I make a gap between this text and the text background?

Tags: html, css, text

right now my div looks like this:

```
    .codeText{
                background-color: #2C3E50 ;
                color: white;
                display:inline-block;
                border-radius: 25px;
             }
```

when I use it on a `<p>` like this:

```
<div class="codeText">
            <p> <code>&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;</code></p>
        </div>
```

The output looks like this:

[Code output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBlN5.png)

What I want is for there to be a little gap between the text and the background. (gaps on the red arrows shown on the screenshot)

**edit:** I want to implement this into the `.codeText{}` and not inline so I can use in multiple areas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could add some padding and width to the codeText

```css
.codeText {
    background-color: #2C3E50;
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding-inline: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="codeText">
      <p> <code>&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;</code></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `padding-left` and `padding-right` properties to the codeText class dan add width to the class codeText, like my code

```css
    .codeText{
                background-color: #2C3E50 ;
                color: white;
                display:inline-block;
                border-radius: 25px;
                padding-left : 10px;
                padding-right : 10px;
                width : 220px;
                text-align : center;
             }
```

```html
<div class="codeText">
            <p> <code>&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;</code></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline) (padding-inline is [`padding-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-left) + [`padding-right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-right))

```css
.codeText{
                background-color: #2C3E50 ;
                color: white;
                display:inline-block;
                border-radius: 25px;
                padding-inline: 5px;
             }
```

```html
<div class="codeText">
            <p> <code>&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;</code></p>
        </div>
```